# Efficiency: Page_load vs Ajax call on page request

Tags: jquery, asp.net

When my page gets hit, is it better practice to have my functionality in the `page_load` of the cs file or in the `$(document).ready(function() {});` have an ajax call to a webmethod?

Which way will be more efficient, I am leaning towards the Ajax call, but my mind is saying that it will be double work? (Load the page and then also call the WebMethod)

Comment: Using AJAX to load initial page content - unless you're implementing site-wide AJAX navigation - seems ridiculous to me. Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Hi Anthony, I just started working on this project, and the current code don't use the Page_Load. And it baffles my mind...

Comment: That's why I'm asking whether there is an actual standard or if it is more like horses for courses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working towards a full scaled JQuery application, I would suggest adding the function in your dom ready. If you do this, you do not have to include the method in the Page_Load. Only declare your jquery function and do a webmethod to return the required data.

Comment: That makes sense, but will there be a performance issue in doing it this way?

Comment: As my answer suggested, there will be. You will be doing 2 calls to the server, instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : it depends on what you want to achieve, and your requirements.

Longer one : if you code takes a few seconds ton run, go for the ajax path : this way you can show the user a waiting icon, letting him know that something is happening, like on gmail that displays a progress bar immediately.

You can also have a look at Firebug "Network" tab to compare both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the back-end of the application you're polling for data. In all reality, a Page_Load will be more efficient as the initial response will send back the data that is required to be displayed initially on the page.

For interoperability and scalability it might be more feasible to perform an AJAX call returning JSON though, as suggested by Rudolf.